# How do I create a 3 nested stamina bar that will regenerate from last to first

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok I have created a stamina container that has three stamina bars within each other, and when you click  on the attack button some of the stamina is taken off the first stamina bar. However, if you keep clicking on the first stamina bar until it depletes to 0 it will then start to deplete the second stamina bar and so on. Now, that is how it was intended to happen, but I'm not able get it to function that way. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g12232ae/) for it, whenever I click on the attack button multiple times the stamina bar is lagging up and once the stamina bar is complete it will still deplete the stamina bar and regnerate itself again. You have to try the jsfiddle to understand what I'm talking about.

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="hBar"> <div class="health"></div></div><!--hbar -->
<div class="sBar">
<div class="s3">
<div class="s2">
<div class="s1">

</div><!--s1 -->
</div><!--s2 -->
</div><!--s3 -->
</div><!--sBar -->
<div class="attack">attack</div>
</div><!--container -->
</body>
```

CSS

```
*{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.hBar{width:400px; height:40px; border:1px solid grey; margin-bottom:20px;}
.health{background:green;width:100%; height:100%;}
.sBar{ width:400px; height:40px; border:1px solid grey; margin-bottom:20px;}
.s3{ width:100%; height:100%; background:red;}
.s2{width:100%; height:100%; background:orange;}
.s1{width:100%; height:100%; background:yellow;}
#container{background:white; width:80%; padding:10px; margin:auto;}
body{background:#CCC;}
.attack{ border-radius:90px; border:black solid 1px; height:75px; width:75px; text-align:center; line-height:75px;}
.attack:hover{cursor:pointer;}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    // one , two, and three variables are collecting the stamina bars
    var one = $('.s1');
    var two = $('.s2');
    var three = $('.s3');
    var oneWidth = one.width();
    var twoWidth = two.width();
    var threeWidth = three.width();
    var stam = $('.sBar').width();
    var damage;
    var subtractHealth;
    var num;

    $('.attack').click(function () {


        // timer is supposed to be the variable for a setInterval function
        let timer;
        // damage is supposed to take away the stamina
        damage = 100;

        // This function is supposed to stop the interval and the animation done on the 
        // stamina bars
        function stopAnimate() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            one.stop();
            two.stop();
            three.stop();

        }


        // if the  first and the second stamina bar is below 0, then add subtract the width to .s3 
        if (oneWidth <= 0 && twoWidth <= 0) {
            subtractHealth = $('.s3').width() - damage;

            three.animate({
                'width': subtractHealth
            }, 'fast');

            // if the first stamina bar is less than 0, the subtract the width of .s2    
        } else if (oneWidth <= 0) {


            subtractHealth = $('.s2').width() - damage;

            two.animate({
                'width': subtractHealth
            }, 'fast');

            // if the first stamina bar is not below 0 then run the content in this 
        } else {



            subtractHealth = $('.s1').width() - damage;

            one.animate({
                'width': subtractHealth
            }, 'fast');


        }



// regenerates all the three stamina bars with the animate method
        function regenerate(stam1, stam2, stam3) {




            stam1.animate({
                'width': stam
            }, 1000, function () {

                if (stam1.width() == stam) {


                    stam2.animate({
                        'width': stam
                    }, 1000, function () {

                        if (stam2.width() == stam) {


                            stam3.animate({
                                'width': stam
                            }, 1000)

                        }// if stam2


                    });//stam2.animate


                }//if stam.width()


            })//stam1.animate

            setTimeout(stopAnimate(), 5000); //end function


        }; //end regenerate 

        // run setInterval and assign the method to timer
        timer = setInterval(regenerate(one, two, three), 1000);




    }); //end click 

}); //end ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain that i have the effect you are after, but if not I think you should be able to modify this code to get the result you seek.  If you would like additional assistance, drop a comment and I will be happy to see what I can do.

```js
  var staminaMax = 1000;
  var staminaCurrent = staminaMax;
  var staminaHealInterval;
  var staminaTick = 100;
  var staminHealPerTick = 10;

  var $sBar3 = $(".sBar .sBarStatus.s3");
  var $sBar2 = $(".sBar .sBarStatus.s2");
  var $sBar1 = $(".sBar .sBarStatus.s1");

  var healStamina = function() {
    staminaCurrent = Math.min(staminaCurrent + staminHealPerTick, staminaMax);
    var rawPct = staminaCurrent / staminaMax;

    var s1Pct = (function() {
      if (rawPct <= (2 / 3)) { return 0; }
      return (rawPct - (2 / 3)) / (1 / 3);
    })();

    var s2Pct = (function() {
      if (rawPct <= (1 / 3)) { return 0; }
      if (rawPct >= (2 / 3)) { return 1; }
      return (rawPct - (1 / 3)) / (1 / 3);
    })();

    var s3Pct = (function() {
      if (rawPct >= (1 / 3)) { return 1; }
      return (rawPct - (0 / 3)) / (1 / 3);
    })();

    $sBar3.css("width", 100 * s3Pct + "%");
    $sBar2.css("width", 100 * s2Pct + "%");
    $sBar1.css("width", 100 * s1Pct + "%");

    if (staminaCurrent >= staminaMax) {
      clearInterval(staminaHealInterval);
      staminaHealInterval = null;
    }
  };

  var dingStamina = function(amount) {
    staminaCurrent = Math.max(staminaCurrent - amount, 0);
    if (!staminaHealInterval) {
      staminaHealInterval = setInterval(healStamina, staminaTick);
    }
  }

  $('.attack').click(function() {
    dingStamina(100);
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.hBar {
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.health {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.sBar {
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.sBar .sBarStatus {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.s3 {
  background: red;
}
.s2 {
  background: orange;
}
.s1 {
  background: yellow;
}
#container {
  background: white;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
body {
  background: #CCC;
}
.attack {
  border-radius: 90px;
  border: black solid 1px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
}
.attack:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="hBar">
    <div class="health"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="sBar">
    <div class="sBarStatus s3"></div>
    <div class="sBarStatus s2"></div>
    <div class="sBarStatus s1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="attack">attack</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bro, this is amazing. I'm still trying to figure out why you decided to have fraction if statements for  the s1Pct, s2Pct, and s3Pct. So for the case of s1Pct, if rawPct is less than 2/3 it will return 0? I don't understand the logic behind it

Comment: So, I assumed each color should represent 1/3 of your stamina.  After eating through 1/3 the yellow would be gone leaving just the orange, then after 2/3 was used the orange would be depleted and you would start eating into the red.  If that makes sense.  So, if you had 50% stamina, we know that the yellow width should be 0 as at 50% we are eating into the orange